# what is exactly a JPanel,JFrame,JLayeredPane and JRootpane

Tags: java, swing

i am new to java while reading i came across various frames and panels,confused between JFrame ,JLayeredPane ,JRootPane and JPannel what is diffrence between them is it possible to use both  JFrame and JPanel  in single class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the picture here

[image: Frame construction diagram] from [the German Java Tutorial page](http://www.java-tutorial.org/jframe.html).

Some details

- The **JFrame** is the window, which is shown as a Top Level Window of Your operating system.
- JFrame is composed of more than one functional elements. One of them, for example, eases the burden of implementing the tooltips correctly: the **LayeredPane**. Among others, it takes care that the tooltips are drawn always on top of everything else.
- The **ContentPane** is the most sensible place to put the main content.
- The **JPanel** is an universal container. The number one class You'd use to put buttons and forms into.

[The official Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) sums up the design very well.

Let's do a minimal example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SomeFrame {

    public static void main(String [] as) {
        // let's make it as simple as possible
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hi!");
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The code above would produce a Frame, but not really usable:

[image: Step 1. Visible frame]

Let's make it a little bigger, only to expose the title:

```
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hi!");
    jFrame.setSize(200, 50);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Result:

[image: Step 2. Set frame size]

Now, lets see if we can add any component into the frame. Let's add a label - in Swing it's realized by the class `JLabel`:

```
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hi!");
    jFrame.setSize(200, 100);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello Swing!");
    jFrame.add(label);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

[image: Step 3. Basic label]

Ok, so what we have done? Added the `JLabel` into the `JFrame`. If You'll look into the Swing code, internally the `JFrame.add()` method adds the component into the **ContentPane**. So the above code is equivalent to:

```
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hi!");
    jFrame.setSize(200, 100);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello Swing!");
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(label);         // <----
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

You can check by yourself that the ContentPane is realized internally by a JPanel. It's in the Swing code:

```
// this invocation...
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hi!");

// effectively invokes following methods:

public JFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
    // ...
    frameInit();
}

protected void frameInit() {
    // ...
    setRootPane(createRootPane());
    // ...
}

protected JRootPane createRootPane() {
    JRootPane rp = new JRootPane();
    // ...
}

public JRootPane() {
    setGlassPane(createGlassPane());
    setLayeredPane(createLayeredPane());
    setContentPane(createContentPane());
    // ...
}

protected Container createContentPane() {
    JComponent c = new JPanel();             // <----
    // ...
    return c;
}
```

Comment: what whould be the position of JPanel if placed in above diagram

Comment: For the typical usage scenario, tt would be exactly **the ContentPane**.

Comment: if we can add all the stuff to JFrame than why do we need JPanel

Comment: JPanel is the most universal container. The JFrame, JDialog, JTabbedPane and others are the specific ones. JPanel has nothing but the content. It is internally used by the JFrame. **ContentPane is an instance of JPanel**.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oracle Swing Tutorials found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html):

> A layered pane is a Swing container that provides a third dimension for positioning components: depth, also known as Z order. When adding a component to a layered pane, you specify its depth as an integer. The higher the number, closer the component is to the "top" position within the container. If components overlap, the "closer" components are drawn on top of components at a lower depth. The relationship between components at the same depth is determined by their positions within the depth

JPannel is a way to help to organize your component in the JFrame and it is not showing only if you set it as visible

JFrame the background where all the component in

According to [The Definitive Guide to Java Swing - Page 235](http://books.google.com/books?id=YPjZNlEgAMcC&pg=PA235&lpg=PA235&dq=The%20JRootPane%20class%20acts%20as%20a%20container%20delegate%20for%20the%20top-level%20Swing%20containers&source=bl&ots=GOcqhZb_dg&sig=QYQOxzOxP9cSFXfzxzJmXpqD6n0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mG36UoK1MIjL0wHe5IGoBg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=The%20JRootPane%20class%20acts%20as%20a%20container%20delegate%20for%20the%20top-level%20Swing%20containers&f=false)

> The JRootPane class acts as a container delegate for the top-level Swing containers i don't need it know just learn JFrame and JPanel

Comment: Please be careful in copy-pasting material from outside sources without giving them proper credit.  Always be sure to quote the material and include the source.  (I have already updated your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You are a beginner right, so before going into UI development with Java, do get some basics like Object Orientation, Exception Handling, Interfaces, Packages etc. Some knowledge on Applets would also held.

Anyway, back to question, JFrame, JLayeredPane, JRootPane and JPanel are all components of Java UI kit called Swing. It is extended from AWT.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) should help.